# Git submodules and rebar

Tags: git, erlang, git-submodules, mochiweb, rebar

My application uses Mochiweb. As I understand, `rebar` fetches the latest version from Github when I run `make`, because there is a line in `rebar.config`:

```
{deps, [
  {mochiweb, ".*",
   {git, "git://github.com/mochi/mochiweb.git", "master"}}
```

My application has a VCS and it is git. So, essentially I have one git repository inside another:

```
myapp
 .git
 deps
  mochiweb
   .git
 src
 etc
```

I know that adding a git repository inside another one is not a good idea (`git add .`). Git submodules functionality should be used instead.

So, I added the `deps/mochiweb` directory as a submodule to the main git repository.

The problem is that when another developer clones the main repository he has to `init` and `update` the submodules first in order to get `deps/mochiweb` (otherwise it would be empty).

If the developer just runs `make` right after he clones the main repository, the Makefile says the following:

```
ERROR: Dependency dir deps/mochiweb failed application validation with reason:

{missing_app_file,"deps/mochiweb"}

make: *** [all] Error 1
```

My question is:
What is the proper way of adding another app to the deps of an Erlang app to allow easy updates by the other developers without using git submodules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the proper way of adding another app to the deps of an Erlang
>   app to allow easy updates by the other developers without using git
>   submodules?

Add the app to the rebar.config and use:

```
./rebar update-deps
```

For updating. The first time, you need to use:

```
./rebar get-deps
```

See: https://github.com/basho/rebar/wiki/Rebar-commands

Now, back to your error.

My feeling is that you have an (almost) empty directory for mochiweb in your deps, probably as a result of playing with Git submodules. When you run the `get-deps` command, rebar silently discards mochiweb, since the directory is already there. But it expects an OTP application and looks for the `mochiweb.app` file, which is not there (the directory is  empty). Therefore, the error. If my interpretation is correct, you can simply do:

```
rm -rf deps/mochiweb
./rebar get-deps
```

Having a look to your rebar.config would help, though.

Comment: After spending almost three days on this issue trying to push to heroku. This finally solved the problem.......

Answer (score 4):

In our internal Erlang projects we use [Git subtree merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) approach to reference dependencies. In my view even though `rebar get-deps` is handly way to get dependencies for a `github` hosted project it is not that good in a corporate environment:

1. `github` needs to be accessible from every build-machine (and the sources for the dependencies are hardcoded in `rebar.config`)
2. You rely on dependent project visioning which is not that precise (can you point to the specific commit?). Not only it isn't possible to reproduce the state of your project in the past (with all the dependencies at that time) but even worse, your project can also be easily broken once some dependency is updated on `github` (without updating its version).
3. What if you want to customise dependent project? Like a small change in a dependent project's 'rebar.config' file?

So instead of `get-deps` we use a separate branch (+ remote pointing to specific `github` project) for every dependent project and git subtree merge it into 'dep' directory on our project branch. Effectively we store all the dependencies in the main branch but that way we solve all above problems:

1. You get entire code base by pulling the project main branch (or dev etc.) from our internal git repositories. It is immediately buildable.
2. The precise versions of all dependencies are subtree merged into our main branch and we update to a newer version of a dependency only when we want/need to: just switch to dependency branch, do `git pull` and them subtree merge some specific version of the dependency into main branch. At any time you can get any past version of the entire project.
3. Dependency can be customised in its own branch (or another customised branch) once it is time to update the dependency: you will have to `git merge` the latest code with your changes but it is usually not a problem. You can even point your remote to your own repository (forked on `github` or internal).

Of course we would not publish our project in this form (with all dependencies included) on 'github' but you can strip all dependencies (by removing the 'dep' folder) on a separate branch and publish the result. The drawback of this approach is a little bit of hassle with dependency updates: instead of `rebar get-deps` you have to do `git push` + `git merge -s subtree` for every dependency you want to update but it is just a consequence of the strict dependency management and easiness of the build.

Comment: I really like this approach. Thanks for sharing your workflow.

Comment: You can also fork the github repo and then depend on your own copy at github. You can tag the version that you depend on and configure the tag in rebar.conf. This way all the insecurity goes away and you can also still use the version later (because the rebar.conf is also version controlled in your main repository)  Btw I had never any problems to access github.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the rebar get-deps command. Take a look at the [Makefile](https://github.com/basho/riak/blob/master/Makefile) and [rebar.config](https://github.com/basho/riak/blob/master/rebar.config) used by Riak for a good example.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have a get-deps command in my rebar.config and that is where it fails (I suppose) when I run the Makefile.

Comment: Can you share what you have right now in your Makefile and rebar.config?